# Добавить поле в пользовательский тип в определенное место

Tags: postgresql

Есть тип:

```
create type public.my_custom_type as
(
    some_field int,
    some_another_field text
);
```

Есть ли хитрость, чтоб добавить новое поле не в конец, а между этими двумя полями?
Что-то вроде:

```
alter type public.my_custom_type add attribute new_field int after some_field;
```

Тут ошибка синтаксиса на слове `after`, которое, видимо, работает только для перечислений. Без `after` все работает, но новое поле добавляется в конец.

Удалить и создать заново проблематично, так как у меня каскадно пол базы удалится.

Comment: А чем вызвана подобная надобность?

Comment: @Ainar-G Есть ряд процедурок, из них удобно пользоваться типом, в котором однотипные данные сгруппированы вместе. В данном случае это внешние ключи. Если добавить в конец, получится структура вроде `{идентификатор, внешний ключ, данные, данные, данные, внешний ключ}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем придумал такой *колхоз*:

Удаляю все поля, которые идут после нужной мне позиции. Далее вставляю свое поле, после чего возвращаю удаленные поля:

```
alter type public.my_custom_type drop attribute some_another_field;
alter type public.my_custom_type add attribute new_field int;
alter type public.my_custom_type add attribute some_another_field text;
```

В итоге новое поле оказывается на нужной мне позиции.

Некрасиво, но не знаю как по-другому.

Comment: всё верно, нормального способа нет, то же, что и с порядком столбцов в таблице: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Alter_column_position

Answer (score 1):

Некоторые СУБД (ЕМНИП, *MySQL*) позволяют вставлять столбцы в неконечную позицию таблицы, используя синтаксис типа

```sql
ALTER TABLE t ADD COLUMN c2 AFTER c1;
```

*PostgreSQL* к ним, увы, не относится: ни в столбцах таблиц, ни в атрибутах типов.